# Coloring by an unsigned char array

Tags: paraview

I have a data set with some points+vertices and an unsigned char array named "Colors" (on the Cell Data) where every tuple is (255,0,0) (i.e. indicating that all of the vertices should be red). In the Information tab, it looks as expected:

[image]

However, in the Properties tab, when I set Coloring to "Colors", I have to choose between Magnitude, X, Y, and Z, none of which are what I want. Instead, I want to use the actual vector to provide the RGB coloring.

[image]

Can anyone explain how to specify that these are actually colors and should be used directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After coming across [this post](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2013-March/027922.html), I learned that you have to uncheck "Map Scalars" in the Advanced section of Properties.

"Clicking the gear icon next to the search bar will show all properties
for the current source/representation and the map scalars/interpolate
scalars should be among them."